# Using VBA Regular Expressions to identify strings that do not contain a specific word

Tags: regex, vba, excel

Using VBA Regular Expresions, I'm trying to find cells in Excel that contain the string "CK" and that do not contain the string "AS", but it keeps blocking any string starting with either A or S. I'm using the following expresion:

```
pattern1 = "^[^AS](.*)CK(.*)"
```

I've seen negative lookahead being suggested, but none of the suggested expresions that I've seen (mostly for other programming languages) have not worked with VBA-Excel.

Any hints?

Comment: Should the cell matches, if it contains both `CK` and `AS`?

Comment: `[^AS]` is a character class, means not A nor S.

Comment: The idea is that it should contain CK but it should not contain AS in the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Without assertions it could be done like this (but it's tough):

`'the idea is that it should contain CK but it should not contain AS in the very beginning'`

`^(?:A[^SC].*CK|AC[^K].*CK|ACK|CK|[^A].*CK).*$`

Formatted

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      A [^SC] .* CK 
   |  
      AC [^K] .* CK 
   |  
      ACK 
   |  
      CK
   |  
      [^A] .* CK 
 )
 .* 
 $
```

---

Or, AS not anywhere in the string

`^(?:[^A]|A[^S])*(?:ACK|CK)(?:[^A]|A(?:[^S]|$))*$`

Formatted

```
 ^   
 (?:
      [^A] 
   |  
      A 
      [^S] 
 )*
 (?:
      ACK
   |  
      CK
 )
 (?:
      [^A] 
   |  
      A 
      (?: [^S] | $ )
 )*
 $
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern

```
^(?!AS).*CK.*
```

`(?!AS)` is a negative lookahead for `AS`, in which `(?! )` is provided by VBA for negative lookaheads. Note that lookbehinds are not provided by VBA, by comparison. Read more:

https://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html

https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead